# A word/phrase for an "I-should-have...." kind of feeling?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am trying to find a word for a feeling in a scenario that goes something like this:

Suppose I was shopping for a watch at a place. I found the watch in Shop A and bought it at $30. Hours later, I saw a similar watch in Shop B selling at only $10. That is $20 cheaper. I felt like "oh my god, I should have not bought so early!".

In the example above, I felt devastated? No, I don't think I feel devastated. It's not that bad. I probably just felt "shucks *only if* I had....". But what's a proper word/phrase to describe this?

Is there a word or a phrase for this ahh-shucks-I-should-have-done-it-differently feeling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the specific case you mention, the usual phrase is [**buyer's remorse**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buyer%27s_remorse).

More generally, I think the word you want is [**regret**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/regret): "a sense of loss, disappointment, dissatisfaction, etc."